# In Google Calendar, if I remove an event's guests and then save it, will it notify the guests by e-mail?

Tags: google-calendar

I imported some Thunderbird events into Google Calendar and, without my permission, it e-mails all the guests of the event. I now want to delete the event from Google Calendar, but I do not want it to re-send all those e-mails like it did last time. Can I delete the event? Or if I remove all the guests and then delete the event, will it still send the e-mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove or otherwise change guests on an event, then save it, you should be prompted whether or not guests should receive a notification. Something similar to:

[image: confirmation dialog]

Simply click "Don't send" and none of the people you removed will get notifications. It should just be silently removed from their calendar.

There is a similar confirmation when you delete an event.

Comment: Thank you! I was too scared to even try saving it. I just removed it from my calendar.